# Packet received on monitor interface, but not main interface

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, wifi, tcpdump

I am building UDP packets from scratch (including 802.11 MAC, LLC, IP and UDP headers) and injecting them into a wireless network using LORCON. The receiving host has an interface `wlan0` in regular, managed mode (but not connected to any AP), and I've added a sub-interface `mon0` running in monitor mode as such:

```
iw dev wlan0 interface add mon0 type monitor
```

Watching the monitoring interface shows that the packet is received correctly:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -vei mon0 udp
tcpdump: WARNING: mon0: no IPv4 address assigned
tcpdump: listening on mon0, link-type IEEE802_11_RADIO (802.11 plus radiotap header), capture size 65535 bytes
<time> <signal info> DA:Broadcast BSSID:... SA:... LLC, dsap SNAP (0xaa) Individual, ssap SNAP (0xaa) Command, ctrl 0x03: oui Ethernet (0x000000), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800): (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 53)
    10.0.0.1.1234 > 255.255.255.255.1234: UDP, length 17
```

However, if I run `sudo tcpdump -vei wlan0`, no packets are printed, even though both the MAC and IP destination addresses are set to the broadcast address. The source address is set to a ficticious address, but I don't think that should prevent `tcpdump` from seeing the packet at all?

```
$ ip link
...
7: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:21:6a:c5:3e:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: mon0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ieee802.11/radiotap 00:21:6a:c5:3e:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

For what it's worth, setting `net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0` as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/163244/linux-kernel-not-passing-through-multicast-udp-packets) has no effect. Neither does setting `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`. Enabling `net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians` produces no output in the syslog.

Any pointers as to why this might be are most welcome!

FWIW, the machine is running Ubuntu 12.04.3, but with the 3.5.7 kernel.

EDIT: Here's something interesting I just discovered: `tcpdump -i any` doesn't print anything either. Only when I explicitly run `tcpdump -i mon0` do I see the incoming packet. Why would something be excluded from `-i any`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many fruitless experiments, I decided to simply put the main interface in monitor mode with

```
iw dev wlan0 set type monitor
ip link set wlan0 promisc on
```

And then use pcap to extract the packets in questions. Adds a dependency on pcap, but also significantly easier it seems than trying to figure out packets go in the Linux kernel. A good intro to pcap can be found [here](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html).